# "Error in `[.data.frame`(database, , apollo_control$indivID) : undefined columns selected" in R studio

Tags: r

At this moment i want to create a model from apollo packages. I import the data from .txt file and want to create appollo_fixed variable.Then, this error message occured. (The data was imported succesfully)

> apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()
> Error in `[.data.frame`(database, , apollo_control$indivID) :
> undefined columns selected

The code I use is shown here,

```
rm(list = ls())
### Load libraries
library(apollo)
### Initialise code
apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control = list(
     modelName  ="MNL",
     modelDescr ="Simple MNL model on mode choice data",
     indivID    ="id")

# ####################################################### #
#### 2. Data loading                                   ####
# ####################################################### #

mydata <- read.table("/Documents/Travelmode_Final_project.txt", header=TRUE)
database = mydata
rm(mydata)

# ####################################################### #
#### 3. Parameter definition                           ####
# ####################################################### #

### Vector of parameters, including any that are kept fixed during estimation
apollo_beta=c(shuttlebus=0,
               citybus=0,
               bike=0, 
               ubike=0,
               motorbike=0,
               car=0,
               mrt=0,
               taxi=0,
               b_SB_TC=0,
               b_SB_TT=0,
               b_CB_TC=0,
               b_CB_TT=0,
               b_B_TC=0,
               b_B_TT=0,
               b_UB_TC = 0,
               b_UB_TT=0,
               b_M_TC=0,
               b_M_TT=0,
               b_C_TC=0,
               b_C_TT=0,
               b_MRT_TT=0, 
               b_MRT_TC=0,
               b_T_TT=0,
               b_T_TC=0)

apollo_fixed = c("shuttlebus")

# ####################################################### #
#### 4. Input validation                               ####
# ####################################################### #

apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()
```

Is there any solution I may need to change to solve this error? Or any potential reasons that may cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

sry for the late answer. Saw this post while searching something else apollo-related. Now you tell apollo that there is a column named "id" in your data that identifies the individual that made that response. For example used to correlate the responses if more than one response per individual is recorded. Setting it is however a requirement; So even if there is only one response per individual this should be a 1:n column giving every individual/response a number. Anyway, it seems apollo can not find/read that column in your database?

Hope this still helps...